# How do I run terminal-based commands on Settings > Keyboard and Shortcuts > Add Custom Shortcuts Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, settings

**New Update**

So after following @FedonKadifeli comment down below, he suggested that I put it on a separate file. So what I actually did is I created a custom command `launch_android_studio` and put it on `~/bin/`. I integrated this command in the `.profile` in my home directory. I can launch this command in the terminal just fine.

Now when I put this command on the Settings > Keyboards and Shortcut > Set Custom Shortcut, nothing happens.

Maybe there is something wrong in my OS? Has anyone here able to make this work?

**Old Update**

I just switched to Ubuntu 20.10 this week and was playing around with Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > Add Custom Shortcut. So I filled up the requested fields but I am stuck in command. I want to run this command when I setup for this:

```
gnome-terminal -- cd ~/DevSpace/AndroidStudio/arctic_fox/bin/ &&  ./studio.sh
```

[image: Screenshot from 2020-12-28 00-30-17]

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly but after presing crtl+alt+A, my Android Studio doesn't run but the command works fine if I run it on terminal.

So my question is, how do I set this up? How do I run terminal commands when doing shortcuts?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend putting the command `cd ~/DevSpace/AndroidStudio/arctic_fox/bin/ && ./studio.sh` into a shell script file and running that file after `gnome-terminal --`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I tried doing this but it seems I cannot run the file. It spits out sh:0. I followed tutorials on how to write a simple shell script but to no avail.

Comment: Does the shell script file start with a `#!/bin/bash` line? Is it executable: `chmod +x ~/bin/launch_android_studio`? Did you enter the command for the shortcut like this: `gnome-terminal -- ~/bin/launch_android_studio`?

Comment: Yes @FedonKadifeli, in fact I followed your suggestion and was able to run my custom command in the terminal just fine. But nothing happens after I keyed in and saved this command in Settings > Keyboard and Shortcuts > Add Custom Command. I have to restart the machine to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I have to restart my computer. After restarting, it finally detects the new keybindings and was able to run my command.

So here is what I did:

- To create your custom command, create a file, say 'hello' and put this in `~bin` directory. (I think you can put it anywhere)
- Add the following line `export PATH=$PATH":~/bin/"` on the `./profile` in home directory. Make sure you show hidden files.
- Then write your own command line like the following:

  ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Write your command line down below
  ```
- Save file
- Then `$ . .profile` to load the changes
- On the terminal, launch the command line you just created
- Now on Settings > Keyboard and Shortcut > Add Custom Shortcut, fill up the fields and on command field, type in the command you just created.

At least on my situation, nothing happens after saving the shortcut. What worked for me is to restart the machine after saving.